# Include user data in different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm trying to render an activity list in the form of json so I can use that data in my AngularJS app. This is my activities controller:

```
def index
  @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc")
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json do
      render :json => @activities.to_json()
    end
  end
end
```

And it renders the json like this:

```
{"id":3,"trackable_id":6,"trackable_type":"Movie","owner_id":1,"owner_type":"User","key":"movie.create","parameters":{},"recipient_id":null,"recipient_type":null,"created_at":"2015-12-30T12:31:24.765Z","updated_at":"2015-12-30T12:31:24.765Z"},
{"id":2,"trackable_id":5,"trackable_type":"Movie","owner_id":1,"owner_type":"User","key":"movie.create","parameters":{},"recipient_id":null,"recipient_type":null,"created_at":"2015-12-30T11:55:06.766Z","updated_at":"2015-12-30T11:55:06.766Z"},
```

As you can see there is a value called `owner_id`. This coincides with the `user id` of the user that did the activity.

I of course have a user model with name, email etc. values. So for the first user with the id 1 it looks like this,

```
{"id":1,"email":"john@doe.nl","name":"John Doe"},
```

Is it possible to check the `owner_id` in the activities and find the `user_id` that coincides, and then add the name, email, etc. value to the activity controller?

The result would be a json render like this:

```
{"id":3,"trackable_id":6,"trackable_type":"Movie","owner_id":1,"email":"john@doe.nl","name":"John Doe","owner_type":"User","key":"movie.create","parameters":{},"recipient_id":null,"recipient_type":null,"created_at":"2015-12-30T12:31:24.765Z","updated_at":"2015-12-30T12:31:24.765Z"},
{"id":2,"trackable_id":5,"trackable_type":"Movie","owner_id":1,"email":"john@doe.nl","name":"John Doe","owner_type":"User","key":"movie.create","parameters":{},"recipient_id":null,"recipient_type":null,"created_at":"2015-12-30T11:55:06.766Z","updated_at":"2015-12-30T11:55:06.766Z"},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure! Just include it in your `to_json` method:

```
render :json => @activities.to_json(include: :owner)
```

Assuming that `activity` `has_one` `owner`

You can also choose to include only specific attributes from the included model. More information on how to handle these serializations can be found in the [to_json Rails Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html)

Comment: Hey Wes, thank you for input. It looks like its working. I do have a question though, how does Rails know what owner is? This is all going through the Public Acitivity gem, I haven't defined owner myself anywhere.

Comment: The gem must define the association based on the `activity` having the `owner_id` attribute. By looking at the gem docs, it looks like `owner` is the default name for the association

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks, I do have another issue though, maybe you can check it to see if you can think of a solution. I've updated my question with the issue. In either case, thank you for the help.

Comment: @PeterBoomsma you should post a new question as a new question on SO. Otherwise, it makes this original question's answers insufficient. Posting as a new question gives you the best chance of getting the best answer (from myself or someone else). :) Feel free to link to it in the comments or original question

Comment: Will do. Thought it would be okay because it's kind of the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use active_model_serializers gem, then create a serializer for your users and activities:

```
# app/serializers/user_serializer.rb
class AuthorSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name ...
end

# app/serializers/activity_serializer.rb
class AuthorSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  # some attributes
  has_one :user
end
```